# how to get a value from a dynamic span

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

i would get the value of a dynamic form from a jsp to a servlet.
the code in the jsp is the following

```
function AggiungiRiga(n_righe){


var numero_righe = n_righe.value;
var box = document.getElementById('box_righe');
if(isNaN(numero_righe)==true){
    box.innerHTML='';
}else{
    var righe = "";
    // Inserisco una riga ad ogni ciclo
    for( i=1; i<=numero_righe; i++){
        righe = righe+""+i+") Ricercatore  : <input type='text' name='rata"+i+" size='10'  maxlength='10'/><br/>";
        String s=rata1.florinda();
        out.println(s);
        }box.innerHTML=righe;

}
  return numero_righe;
 }
```

in the servlet, i would get the value of "rata"+i.
how i can do this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your doGet or doPost method based on form type in servlet you can iterate all parameters and check if parameter starts with **rata** then its accepted

to get all parametes names use **request.getParameterNames()** which will return Enumeration.

```
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
    String param = params.nextElement();
    if(param.startsWith("rata")){
         String value = request.getParameter(param); 
         //your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap your textbox in a form tag.

```
// Inserisco una riga ad ogni ciclo
for( i=1; i<=numero_righe; i++){
    righe = righe+""+i+") Ricercatore  : <input type='text' 
                           name='rata"+i+" size='10'  maxlength='10'/><br/>";
    String s=rata1.florinda();
    out.println(s);
    }
    //Adding form tag  and submit button
    //Aggiunta di tag forma e pulsante di invio
    box.innerHTML="<form method=post action=myservlet >"
                     +righe
                     +"<input type=submit name=submit value=Submit />"
                     +"</form>";
```

So when you click the submit button, the form will get submitted by all the values in your all textboxes.

**MyServlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException,IOException{
    Enumeration<String> rataList = request.getParameterNames();

   while(rataList.hasMoreElements()){
    request.getParameter(rataList.nextElement()); 
    //Do what you want here 
    //Fate quello che volete qui
    }


 }
```